# Gyro substitute for turtlebot

Tags: ros, gyro, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The [suggested gyro](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9059) for turtlebot is no longer available at Sparkfun.com. Does someone knows which other gyro can be used?

Thanks in advance,

Lucas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11161/gyro-substitute-for-turtlebot/) by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2011-09-09

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you're looking for a breakout board that will also work you can use http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8372 , it's not a drop in replacement but if you're looking for a breakout board this will work

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-18**:
all you need is a 5V gyro.. it doesn't really matter how many axis and it should be somewhere between 150-300deg/sec

**Comment by [Marco](https://answers.ros.org/users/920/marco/) on 2011-09-15**:
For those willing to pay a high price for the adxrs613 breakout box there are still a few in stock at http://www.active-robots.com/sensors/gyros/gyro-breakout-board-adxrs613.html

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2011-09-15**:
I think that $ 60 is very expensive for a single axis gyro breakout board... Is possible to use a dual or triple axis gyro? Because Sparkfun has other cheaper options: http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10100

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-15**:
either will work, with the 300deg/s gyro you will need to claibrate you TurtleBot the default values will not be close enough. the board you suggest above would be a better choice because the default calibration values will be close and you might not need to calibrate.

**Comment by [Marco](https://answers.ros.org/users/920/marco/) on 2011-09-14**:
Would the e2 version of above, http://www.active-robots.com/sensors/gyros/gyro-breakout-board-mlx90609-e2.html , be an even better alternative, as it is also 150/s and has imilar sensitivity to the adxrs613?

**Comment by [Marco](https://answers.ros.org/users/920/marco/) on 2011-09-13**:
Besides the sensitivity being twice as low and the max speed twice as high, it seems similar to ad adxrs613. What kind of changes (software/hardware) are needed in order for this gyro to function correctly in the turtlebot package?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We haven't been able to find a drop-in replacement for that breakout. Our latest run of boards use an [ADXRS652BBGZ](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&site=us&keywords=ADXRS652BBGZ+&x=0&y=0). Unfortunately, this is a BGA package, requiring you to use a hot-plate to solder this chip to the board before adding other parts.
It also has a different scale (250 deg/s instead of 150 deg/s).

There are also a few other support components (caps and a resistor) that are required. We're getting those fixes into the latest parts package soon.

At the moment, we haven't found anything which is pin-compatible and easy to hand solder.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2011-09-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2